# What is wrong with my solution for a combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is:

> We want to place m men and n women at a round table with $\left(m+n\right)$ chairs in such a way that no two men sit next to each other. In how many ways can this be done?

I approached the problem in the following way. Knowing that between each man there **have to be at least one woman** and they are sitting at the round table, then we are left with $\left(n-m\right)$ women to arrange. There are exactly $m$ places (gaps, so $m-1$ walls dividing these places) to put women, there are $P_0\left(n-m, m-1\right)=\frac{(n-m+m-1)!}{\left(n-m\right)!\left(m-1\right)!}=\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-m\right)!\left(m-1\right)!}$ ways to arrange women in these places (arrangement with repetitions of elements with 2 types). Then as on each chair sits only either man or woman, I multiplied the answer by $2$ (it is like shifting all combinations by 1 chair). So $2m!n!\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-m\right)!\left(m-1\right)!}$

But the real answer is $m!n!\left[\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-m\right)!\left(m-1\right)!} + \frac{n!}{\left(n-m\right)!m!}\right]$. Explaining that we fix one chair and consider 2 cases, when here sits man, and then woman. This solution is clear, and I got it. But I can't anyway understand why my solution fails. Rather, I can't understand how to "see" the second case from my approach. What I can see is that I need to shift, but I don't find fixing a chair necessary. I will really appreciate if you at least show which cases I don't consider or instead calculate twice, etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming the women are different, you might not be counting different ways that two women could sit next to each other.  More precisely, if you have three women sitting next to each other, there are $3!$ ways to arrange the women.  This doesn't seem to show up in your calculation.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I count it. First they can differ by their chair number which is $n!$ ways. And I fill $m$ gaps with left $\left(n-m\right)$ women. So in the end several women can set next to each other and not violating the condition.

Comment: it probably depends on if the people are considered different. etc.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, yes, of course. They are different.

Comment: see that's an assumption, it could be in this problem, that all women are considered indistinguishable in which case it changes the math.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, but the right answer is known. And the multiplication by $n!$ shows that they are distinguishable.

Comment: The part about placing $m$ women and then placing $n-m$ women doesn't seem right.  The first $m$ women can never be sitting next to each other and the order of the women sitting in each group can change - it looks like the combinatorics count the number of women in each group, not the order in which they're arranged.

Comment: if all men and all women were distinguishable the total number of possible permutations is (n+m)! that multiplication outside the brackets goes into the edit: numerator of the fractions inside.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, yes exactly. The number of ways women can be placed in groups multiplied by $n!$, I think, should give the total number of arrangements of women.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, the sum inside of brackets calculates the number of ways we can fill chairs either with man or woman (we can say assuming they are indistinguishable). And then for each such combination there are $m!n!$ ways to reorganize men and women. What you say doesn't consider the condition. You just calculate all posible ways to arrange men and women $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ and then multiply to the sum. I think it is a solution, but for another problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume that the seats are numbered clockwise $1,2,…,n+m$ then the count you are trying to double

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-m)!(m-1)!}$$

is the number of configurations with a man in seat $1$ and women in both seats $2$ and $n+m$.

By rotating each such configuration $1$ seat clockwise the man previously in seat $1$ is now in seat $2$ and the two women are now in seats $1$ and $3$.

Your claim is that adding this case accounts for *all* cases where a woman occupies seat $1$, however it only accounts for the cases where there is a woman in seat $1$ *and a man in seat $2$*. It ignores cases where there is a woman in seat $1$ *and a woman in seat $2$*. i.e. It undercounts.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different view:

Your solution does not answer the question.  Let me explain the solution with a different perspective.

Since it is a round configuration, the way you bring it to a line configuration is to fix one chair with either a man or woman.

Suppose you fix a chair seated by a woman, the configuration would stand as below

W _ _ _ _.............. _. The spaces can be filled with any order and now that we want to fill $m$ men around $n-1$ women, we have a total number of arrangements would be(with the $m$ men and $n$ women could be permuted by $m!$ and $n!$)

${(n-1+1)\choose m}. m! n!$

Suppose you fix a chair seated by a man, the configuration would stand as below

M W _ _ _ _ ........._ _W. The spaces can be filled with any order and now that we want to fill $m-1$ men around $n-2$ women, we have a total number of arrangements would be(with the $m$ men and $n$ women could be permuted by $m!$ and $n!$)

${(n-2+1)\choose (m-1)}. m! n! = {(n-1)\choose (m-1)}. m! n!$

Sum of these should get you the answer.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am mostly interested in why my solution doesn't work. What is wrong in my steps of solving? What I misunderstood?
Because most of the steps coincide with the right answer. But as it was mentioned in the comments section, the wrong part is multiplying by two. That seems to me as okay, when actually it is not.

Comment: Well, this is obvious that if m (number of men) > n (number of women) then it is impossible to arrange them to satisfy the condition. I didn't understand completely what you want to ask/say.

Comment: That is why deleted the comment, sorry.

Comment: Could you explain to me the rationale of your shifting by 1 would allow you to multiply by 2.  The shifting by one would help the argument of rotation in a circular arrangement where you have the total number of arraangement to be $(n+m-1)!$.  It do not think it allows to give you the rationale to multiply by 2.

Comment: Because let men sit on seats including the first seat. Then second will always be held by women. Shifting by 1 chair will allow men to occupy second chair as well, which will mean that the same combinations will be repeated but now with inclusion of second chair. For me it is like result + result = 2 * result

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html.  This explains as to when you need to make adjustments for  shifts on circular arrangement and I can only assert that your approach is wrong.  By shifting 1 you don't get a different configuration.

Comment: You are confusing the notion of circle (ring) and round table. In circle positions of elements are determined relatively to each other. But in our case all positions are determined with respect to the table. You can check this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956960/problem-with-concepts-of-circular-permutation

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov, you cannot simply $\times 2$ because $\frac{(n-1)!}{(m-n)!(m-1)!}$ counts configurations where a man sits in seat $1$ say. So by rotating every one of these cases $1$ seat (clockwise for example) will give you a case with a woman in seat $1$, yes, but that woman will always have a man $1$ seat clockwise from her (the man previously occupying seat $1$). This misses all the cases where the woman in seat $1$ has no man on either side.

Comment: @N.Shales, I will really appreciate if you show with some example. Because I can't completely understand what case you are talking about (obviously, if I could, I would not ask this question)

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov, say the seats are numbered clockwise $1,2,\ldots, n+m$ then the count you are trying to double is the number of configurations with a man in seat $1$ and women in seats $2$ and $n+m$. By rotating each such config $1$ seat clockwise the man previously in seat $1$ is now in seat $2$ and the two women are now in seats $1$ and $3$. Your claim is that this accounts for all cases where a woman occupies seat $1$ but it only accounts for the cases where there is a woman in seat $1$ *and* a man in seat $2$. I.e. It undercounts.

Comment: @N.Shales, oh my gosh! :D Thank you very much! Wow, that was really unexpectable for me. Post this as an answer, I will accept it.